# Should I create an ActionForm subclass for a page in which I want to display the data?

Tags: java, struts, struts-1

I want to display data retrieved from a database. Should I create a ActionForm subclass for it?

How should i do it in Struts 1?

Answer (score 0):

The following example should help, you just need to replace the ActorData class with your data access code - http://www.vaannila.com/struts/struts-example/struts-pagination-example-1.html